# Qt, mixing items with and without checkboxes in QListWidget

Tags: qt, checkbox, qlistwidget

Good day everyone. I'm trying to create a filemanager based on `QListWidget`. However, I ran into a problem. In my manager I need to have some items be with checkboxes and the other items to be without them. The problem is that in the items without checkboxes the text and icons are shifted to the left (slightly in `IconView` and substantially in `ListView`).
Is there a way to make the text and icons in all checkboxes be on the same line?

Comment: How can you have a IconView and a ListView of a QListWidget? Are you actually using QListView?

Comment: Well, QListWidget inherits QListWiew and therefore has access to all its functions

Answer (score 0):

Aligning the items in that column to the right seems to be a viable option.

Comment: Yes, it does, only I can't find the function or property responsible for that. Can you promt me in the right direction?

Comment: Does [QListWidgetItem::setTextAlignment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#setTextAlignment) do what you're looking for?

Comment: Sadly no, as it aligns only text, and the icons stay on their old places

Comment: So it does. Have you considered using a QTableView/Widget instead? You could then have the checkbox in the first column and the icons and labels in a second column. This also provides you the option to add additional columns with file properties later. I can provide a little example code if desired.